# Could the definition of singular measures be weakened?

Tags: measure-theory, singular-measures

**The question:**

The standard definition of singular measures is given on Wikipedia:

> Two positive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined on a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$ are called **singular** if there exist two disjoint sets $A,B\in\Sigma$ whose union is $\Omega$ such that $\mu$ is zero on all measurable subsets of $B$ while $\nu$ is zero on all measurable subsets of $A$.

I was wondering what if we weaken the definition to not require $A$ and $B$ to be measurable sets; the rest of the definition is unchanged. Is it then equivalent to the original definition?

---

**"Motivation"**

I was trying to do this because I **misread** the original definition and then I was thinking how nice would it be if $A$ and $B$ were measurable... Then I read the definition again, but the wondering is still here.

I tried some simple tricks like picking a set (call it $X$) at a time which is zero in one measure and non-zero in the other and then define $A$ and $B$ through transfinite recursion (unioning all the sets I picked so far), but I wasn't able to do that either. There is an equivalent definition of absolutely continuous measures, defined in $\delta-\varepsilon$ notation which seems to yield something like "I can pick such $X$ iff the two measures are not absolutely continuous one w.r.t. to the other". But I get lost here... It is as far as my intuition goes. However, I still doubt it could be done that way.

Is anything known about this weakened definition?

---

**Note:**
The opposite question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600615) and the answer to this question given by Eric Wofsey answers exactly that other question.

Comment: Hmm, something is confusing here.  The text you quoted from wikipedia does not say that $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets. It only talks about a condition on the measurable subsets of $A$ and of $B$.  Was that incorrectly copied from wikipedia, or wikipedia should be corrected to assume $A$ and $B$ are measurable?

Comment: I agree with you that's it is confusing. I caught myself just like that. That's why I wrongly read the definition at least twice. The line $A,B\in\Sigma$ says that $A$ and $B$ are measurable. Because $\Sigma$ represents all measurable sets. It is the $\sigma$-algebra of all measurable sets, it defines them. It is tricky to spot, isn't it...

Comment: Ah, yes, nicely spotted!  I missed that.

Comment: I updated wikipedia to make it more obvious.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This weakened definition is much weaker than the usual definition, to the point of being basically useless.  For instance, it can be shown that there exists a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ (e.g., a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set)) such that both $A$ and its complement intersect every set of positive Lebesgue measure.  That is, every Lebesgue measurable subset of either $A$ or its complement has measure $0$.  This means that by your weakened definition, Lebesgue measure is singular with respect to itself!

Comment: Amazing! I asked exactly that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4600615. I will now link these two questions and your answer.